# how to use use possibly with lm?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

dataframe <- data_frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        value = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
dataframe

> dataframe
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id value
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1    NA
2     2    NA
3     3    NA
4     4    NA
5     5    NA
6     6    NA
```

I have a function that essentially uses `lm` to compute the mean of a column in my dataframe.

```
get_mean <- function(data, myvar){
  col_name <- as.character(substitute(myvar))
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(col_name, "~ 1"))
  tidy(lm(data = data, fmla, na.action = 'na.omit')) %>% pull(estimate)
}
```

Now

```
> get_mean(dataframe, id)
[1] 3.5
```

but because of the missing values,

```
get_mean(dataframe, value)
```

returns the dreaded

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

I would like the function to return NA or any number specified by me when the all NA case arise. I tried to use `purrr:possibly` but without success

```
get_mean <- function(data, myvar){
  col_name <- as.character(substitute(myvar))
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(col_name, "~ 1"))
  model <- purrr::possibly(lm(data = data, fmla, na.action = 'na.omit'), NA)
  if(!is.na(model)) {
  tidy(model) %>%  pull(estimate)
  }
}

get_mean(dataframe, id)
```

does not work

> Error: Can't convert a list to function

What should I do?
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `possibly()` here? That's a function that takes a function and returns another function -- none of which you seem to actually really want here.

Comment: ah! I am confused then. I also tried `tryCatch` but without success. I am fine with that you you see a way. thanks!

Comment: Use `tryCatch`. Something like `return(tryCatch(< your lm code >, error = function(e) NA))`.

Comment: I'm working very hard to not ask why you're using `lm` instead of `mean` to calculate means, I'm sure I'll just find the answer frustrating.

Comment: not frustrating at all. This is a toy model to explain my issue. I use `lm` and not `mean` in my full code

Comment: @Gregor but thanks for the nice tone of your remark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the whole function in `possibly`, so you get NA if the whole function fails anywhere.

```
get_mean <- possibly(function(data, myvar) {
     col_name <- as.character(substitute(myvar))
     fmla <- as.formula(paste(col_name, "~ 1"))
     model <- lm(data = data, fmla, na.action = 'na.omit')
     tidy(model) %>%  pull(estimate)
}, otherwise = NA)

get_mean(dataframe, id)
[1] 3.5
 get_mean(dataframe, value)
[1] NA
```

However, unlike `tryCatch` this isn't focused on the `lm` part of the code.  It is working on the whole function, and will return NA if any error occurs for any reason.  For example, if you forgot to load the *broom* package before running `get_mean` you would get `NA` back even if the model worked fine because R wouldn't be able to find `tidy`.

Setting the `quiet` argument to `FALSE` will allow the error message to print, which could help you mitigate errors like the one I outline above.

You can also use `possibly` as in the documentation examples for `safely`, making a `possibly` function specific for `lm` to use.  Then you can use an `if else` statement to either `tidy` or return `NA`.

```
get_mean <- function(data, myvar) {
     col_name <- as.character(substitute(myvar))
     fmla <- as.formula(paste(col_name, "~ 1"))
     poss_lm <- possibly(lm, otherwise = NA)
     model <- poss_lm(data = data, fmla, na.action = 'na.omit')
     if( !is.na(model[1]) ) {
          tidy(model) %>%  pull(estimate)
     }
     else {
          model
     }
}
```

Comment: that's probably even nicer. fail proof :D

Comment: Fail-proof means harder to detect and diagnose problems, harder to fix. aosmith gives a nice example, if somehow `broom` isn't loaded, instead of informative error message you just get all `NA` results...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a regular `tryCatch()` would do the trick

```
get_mean <- function(data, myvar){
  col_name <- as.character(substitute(myvar))
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(col_name, "~ 1"))
  tryCatch(lm(data = data, fmla, na.action = 'na.omit') %>% tidy() %>%  pull(estimate),
                    error=function(e) NA)
}
get_mean(dataframe, id)
# [1] 3.5
get_mean(dataframe, value)
# [1] NA
```